# Answer to the phone with accelerometer change - Android Java

Tags: java, android, call, accelerometer

How to auto answer to a call when accelerometer change to a specific value.

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.values[0] <1) {
       //ANSWER CODE

          //Sometext
       acceleration.setText("ANSWERED");
    }
```

The code from bellow is to answer to a call, but I don't want to press a button. I don't know how to convert this code to add it where is onSensorChanged:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
context.sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem?

Comment: I don't know how to add the code where is onSensorChanged. The autoanswer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something along the lines of

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER);
startActivity(i);
```

The doc for the Intent.ACTION_ANSWER is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_ANSWER), you might want to take a look at it. It seems it doesn't need any extras, so you may be good with this.

Comment: The application has stopped unexpectedly. Mabe is something with the permission.

Comment: Well, there's a ton of stuff that can go wrong. Check your LogCat for the source.